# Separar en dos columnas distintas algo que tengo en la misma

Tags: mysql, sql

El objetivo es que el en último select, la tabla aparezca con la obra más importante, sus respectivos dibujante y escritor, y que en el caso de super-man, aparezca el null (que es el verdadero objetivo del proyecto) pero por mucho que el he dado vueltas, no encuentro ninguna manera de hacer esto. ¿Alguien hecha una mano?

```
CREATE TABLE Artistas (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Nombre TEXT,
    Nacionalidad TEXT,
    Gran_obra INTEGER,
    Casa_Principal INTEGER,
    Dibujante_o_escritor INTEGER);

INSERT INTO Artistas (Nombre,Nacionalidad,Gran_obra, Casa_Principal,Dibujante_o_escritor) VALUES ("Stan Lee", "Americano", 3, 2,1);


INSERT INTO Artistas (Nombre,Nacionalidad,Gran_obra, Casa_Principal,Dibujante_o_escritor) VALUES ("Dave Gibbons", "Inglés", 1, 2,1);


INSERT INTO Artistas (Nombre,Nacionalidad,Gran_obra, Casa_Principal,Dibujante_o_escritor) VALUES ("Sara Pichelli", "Italiana", 4,1,1);

INSERT INTO Artistas (Nombre,Nacionalidad, Gran_obra, Casa_Principal,Dibujante_o_escritor) VALUES ("Alan Moore", "Inglés", 1, 2,2);

INSERT INTO Artistas (Nombre, Nacionalidad, Gran_Obra, Casa_Principal,Dibujante_o_escritor) VALUES("Steve Ditko", "Estadounidense", 3, 1,2 );

INSERT INTO Artistas (Nombre, Nacionalidad, Gran_Obra, Casa_Principal,Dibujante_o_escritor) VALUES ("Brian Michael Bendis", "Estadounidense", 4,1,2);


CREATE TABLE Principales_casas (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Nombre TEXT,
    Fundador TEXT,
    Grandes_Títulos INTEGER);

INSERT INTO Principales_casas (Nombre, Fundador) VALUES ("Marvel", "Martin Goodman");
INSERT INTO Principales_casas (Nombre, Fundador) VALUES ("DC", "    Malcolm Wheeler-Nicholson");
INSERT INTO Principales_casas (Nombre, Fundador)
VALUES ("Vertigo", "Karen Berger"); 


CREATE TABLE Grandes_Obras (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Nombre TEXT);

INSERT INTO Grandes_Obras (Nombre) VALUES ("Watchmen");
INSERT INTO Grandes_Obras (Nombre) VALUES ("Superman");
INSERT INTO Grandes_Obras (Nombre) VALUES ("The Amazing Spider-Man");
INSERT INTO Grandes_Obras (Nombre) VALUES ("Miles Morales");    


/* dibujante= 0 escritor= 1*/
CREATE TABLE DIBOESCR (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, diboescr TEXT,diboescr2 text);
INSERT INTO DIBOESCR (diboescr) VALUES ("Dibujante");
INSERT INTO DIBOESCR (diboescr) VALUES ("Escritor");
INSERT INTO DIBOESCR(diboescr2) VALUES ("Dibujante");
INSERT INTO DIBOESCR (diboescr2) VALUES ("Escritor");



SELECT Artistas.Nombre, DIBOESCR.diboescr as Profesión, Artistas.Nacionalidad, Principales_casas.Nombre as Principal_editorial FROM Artistas

JOIN Principales_casas
JOIN diboescr
ON Artistas.Casa_Principal = Principales_casas.id
WHERE Artistas.Dibujante_o_escritor = DIBOESCR.id;


SELECT Grandes_Obras.Nombre as Obras_Importantes From Grandes_Obras;
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el criterio para determinar cuales son las obras mas importantes y cuales las menos?

Comment: Cada Gran_obra corresponde a la obra más importante un autor, menos la de Superman.

Comment: Te sirvió la respuesta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer es que toda la información te lo traiga según las grandes obras, para eso puedes usar consulta `LEFT JOIN`, que a partir de una gran obra te muestre información del artista, editorial y escritor o dibujante (este último puedes que en esta consulta solo agregas en un solo campo)

```
SELECT Artistas.Nombre, 
DIBOESCR.diboescr as Profesión,
Artistas.Nacionalidad, 
Principales_casas.Nombre as 'Principal editorial'
From Grandes_Obras 
LEFT JOIN
Artistas ON 
Grandes_Obras.id = Artistas.Gran_obra
LEFT JOIN Principales_casas ON 
Artistas.Casa_Principal = Principales_casas.id
LEFT JOIN DIBOESCR ON 
Artistas.Dibujante_o_escritor = DIBOESCR.id;
```

Aquí te dejo un [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/brwhExJ9gaTZ2HyMcjLGrt/0) para que pruebes la consulta donde te muestra el último campo de la fila como null todos los campos, ya que no está asociado a ningún artista.